# Get the properties of highlighted features when de-highlighting one of them in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, features, angular

```
this.map.on('singleclick', event => {
    const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
      console.log(feature);
     return feature
    })
    if(feature instanceof Feature){
      alert(feature.getProperties().JBA_ASSET_ID);
      this.map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry(),{"maxZoom":27} );
      var fill = new Fill({color: 'blue'});
      var stroke = new Stroke({color: 'red',width: 8});
      var styleNew = new Style({ fill,stroke});         
      feature.setStyle(styleNew)
    }
 }

 this.map.on('dblclick', event => {
  const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
    console.log(feature);
    return feature
  })
  if(feature instanceof Feature){
    this.map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry().getExtent(),{"maxZoom":17} );
    var styleNew=undefined      
    feature.setStyle(styleNew)
  }
}
```

From above code when I perform click operation on some features they will be get highlighted. If I perform the double click operation on the highlighted feature it has to be de-highlighted. Now I have to get the properties of the remaining highlighted features. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. What do you mean by "select feature"? Click on it? What do you mean by "unselect feature"? What exactly do you mean by "get attribute as an alert for selected features when I deselect one of those"? You mean `JBA_ASSET_ID` property of all the remaining  selected features? Please edit your question with detailed info.

Comment: @TomazicM now understood my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have list of selected features you can create additional vector source `selectedFeatures` where you add selected feature and remove it, when it's unselected.

Relevant code could then look something like this (tested, plain JS, since I'm not familiar with Angular):

```
var selectedFeatures = new ol.source.Vector();

var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'blue'});
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 8});
var styleNew = new ol.style.Style({fill, stroke});         

map.on('singleclick', event => {
  const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
    return feature;
  })
  if(feature instanceof ol.Feature){
    if (!selectedFeatures.hasFeature(feature)) {
      feature.setStyle(styleNew);
      selectedFeatures.addFeature(feature);
    }
  }
});

map.on('dblclick', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
    return feature;
  })
  if(feature instanceof ol.Feature){
    if (selectedFeatures.hasFeature(feature)) {
      feature.setStyle();
      selectedFeatures.removeFeature(feature);
      var selectedList = '';
      selectedFeatures.forEachFeature(feature => {
        selectedList += feature.getProperties().JBA_ASSET_ID + ' ';
      });
      console.log('Still selected: ' + selectedList);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting error like this-                                                                                                 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ol_uid')
    at getUid (util.js:28)
    at VectorSource.removeFeature (Vector.js:936)
    at Map.<anonymous> (app.component.ts:133)
    at Map.Target.dispatchEvent (Target.js:116)
    at Map.PluggableMap.handleMapBrowserEvent (PluggableMap.js:870)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.Target.dispatchEvent (Target.js:116)
    
   Can you help on this..

Comment: See simplified answer (tested).

Comment: @TomazicM-Thanks you

Comment: @TomazicM-Instead of double click can I add button click .Can you help me on this.